# combining three observables two using forkjoin and one using mergemap

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

Three api calls, in which two of them has no parameter to pass. So I used forkJoin the two api calls, but the third one needs a parameter which is gotten from the first two apis. I have no idea how to implement it.

Here is my code so far.

```
ngOnInit();
{
  const categories$ = this.blogService.getCategories(); // one
  const posts$ = this.blogService.getPosts(); // two

  forkJoin([
    categories$,
    posts$
  ]).pipe(
    map(([categories, posts]) => {
      return posts.map(post => {
        ... // doing some stuff here
        return post;
      });
    }),
    mergeMap(posts => {
      return posts.map(post => this.blogService.getFeaturedImage(post.featured_media)); // three
    }, y => console.log(y))
  ).subscribe();
}
```

In the above code, forkJoin works as I expected. but the third call is not happening. I need to pass a value to the third service. How to do that?

P.S `y returns the value of second call as expected`

Comment: I would suggest  change `getFeaturedImage` into `getFeaturedImages` and make it to get all the images at once. Making request per item is not a good practice.

Comment: But lets say, If I have 100's of featured image, and 100's of posts and 100's of categories, there'll be a hit on performance right, even if I get all at once. Is there any way to improve the performance?

Comment: Making 100 individual requests would hit hard on performance. If you have such range of images i would suggest using `CDN`. It would be better for the storage and traffic  and the site load performance.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code, you were returning an array of observable which needs `forkJoin` (async) or `concat` (sequential) to execute them

```
 mergeMap(posts => {
      return forkJoin(posts.map(post => this.blogService.getFeaturedImage(post.featured_media))); // three
    })
```